# How to get ArcObjects SDK for .NET?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, .net, visual-studio, arcobjects

Forgive my newbness, but how do I get the .NET ArcGIS SDK?  I can't access any of the ArcGIS templates when I create a new project in Visual Studio.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, SP1 and ArcGIS 10.1.

I'm VERY green WRT to programming with ArcObjects and I think I'm missing something really simple!

Comment: It is on the ArcGIS installation media.

Answer (score 2):

Run setup.exe from the SDK_dotnet directory in the ArcGIS Desktop install folder

Comment: Thanks! It's a work computer and I didn't have any installation media.  Finally found the right person to help after this answer!

Answer (score -1):

you need to contact esri's customer care to get an authorization number for VBA.

http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=DD02CFE7-1422-2418-7F271831F47A7A31&questionId=4032

Comment: that's right, but the question is not asking about _ArcObjects VBA SDK_, but about _ArcObjects SDK for .NET_.